# scalability of lock based concurrency

Tags: concurrency

As far as I understand in `lock` based concurrency every thread should `acquire` a `lock` before entering a `critical section`, then do some action inside critical section and `release` a lock, thus allowing other thread to proceed.

But how scallable is that?

Because no matter how many cores or threads you have they will basically work sequentially, one after another due to single lock waiting. How such issues are usually resolved?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that it's **not** scalable to the extent your system is contending on shared locks. Threads serialize on locks, and this can dramatically hurt overall throughput in exactly the way that you describe.

As far as how to address the issue, this is where it gets more complicated, but the essence is still simple - reduce the amount of time you're holding onto a lock that other threads might care about. There are a couple ways to achieve this:

- Reduce the length of time a thread holds onto a lock. This decreases both the likelihood that another thread will have to wait and the time they'd have to wait if they do block.
- Spread the mutual exclusion across multiple locks. Rather than have one lock, maybe you can lock structures separately, so there's less likely to be overlap. (This introduces concerns around lock ordering and deadlock, however.)
- Look into way to avoid locking entirely. You really only have to lock when you're mutating shared structures. You can therefore avoid the need to lock where you can avoid either the mutation or the sharing.

This type of issue turns up a lot in systems software development. For quite some time, the Linux kernel had what was referred to as the 'Big Kernel Lock'... a single lock over most of the critical internal structures. This caused trouble with large numbers of CPU's, and was ultimately removed.

https://kernelnewbies.org/BigKernelLock

Answer (score 0):

Every program has the problem you have described up to a certain point. The way you overcome it is by changing the way you approach your problem.

As we get better with our methodologies of concurrency, we come up with different patterns of concurrency. For example, in actor models, you do not even have to use locking, as the architecture of the program allow you to completely avoid using shared memory. Even with the traditional architecture, the number of locks used will significantly change based on how you design your program.

For traditional locking approach though, design your code in a way that your threads do not frequently try to run the same block of code. Try to keep your shared memory instances low in numbers, so that you do not have to lock so frequently.

Also, if you try to use immutable data structures, you will notice the way you design your concurrent applications will change, and the amount of locks will be reduced.